# Linked list using shared pointer reference counter and no Node class?

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr

Fishing for ideas - I recently came across a programming quiz where this question was asked. Basically you have to implement a linked list using a templated LinkedList class that has a shared pointer member variable of type T. You cannot make a Node class. I figured you could make instances of the shared pointer in the `push_back()` method, and retrieve the length of the linked list using `use_count()` on the pointer, but accessing each instance and inserting/deleting nodes seem to me close to impossible. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just do like `C` linked list, for that seem to work well.

Comment: If the `LinkedList` class holds a single pointer to `T` you would need multiple `LinkedList`s that refer to each other instead of one `LinkedList` with many `node`s.

Comment: I think you left out valuable information when you cut this down to what it "basically" is.

Comment: @molbdnilo not really. That was about it.

Comment: Wouldn't adding a `LinkedList* next` field to your LinkedList solve the problem?

Comment: @Neosapien So, the requirements are that you get one member variable, which is a `shared_ptr<T>`, and you need to implement a `push_back` member function, and can't add anything else?

Comment: Because in many case a linked list is just a node, I guess that this "linked list" is a node having no `data` member but just something acting as the `next` one (the T shared ptr). Since the data is not needed for any of the inserting/deleting/iterating operations, you should manipulate such list as any other linked list (the tail being when the shared_ptr is null).

Comment: @Botje I'm not able to visualise how that would work. Wouldn't that just make each node of the linked list another linked list?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes. I know, I perplexed too. It would have been easy to just add a node class, and implementing all ops would have been a breeze. But without adding that to the boiler plate template provided, I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: @dspr That is why i thought, actually, to ```make_shared``` every time a ```push_back``` is called. So ```empty()``` could just check if it's nullptr, but how to I index/iterate over the reference counter for any of the other ops? Is that even possible?

Comment: @DipStax care to elaborate?